# If passing a negative number to taskDelay function in vxworks, what happens?

Tags: vxworks

Noted that the parameter of taskDelay is of type int, which means the number could be negative. Just wondering how the function is going to react when passing a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

Most functions would validate the input, and just return early/return 0/set the parameter in question to a default value.

Answer (score 0):

I presume there's no critical need to do this in production, and you probably have some code lying around that you could test with.... why not give it a go?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation doesn't address it, and the only error codes they do define doesn't cover this case. The most correct answer therefore is that the results are undefined.

See the [VxWorks / Tornado II FAQ](http://www.xs4all.nl/~borkhuis/vxworks/vxw_pt5.html) for this gem, however:

> taskDelay(-1) shows another bug in
>   the vxWorks timer/tick code. It has
>   the (side) effect of setting vxTicks
>   to zero. This corrupts the localtime
>   (and probably other things). In fact
>   taskDelay(x) will have the same effect
>   if vxTicks + x >= 0x100000000. If the
>   system clock rate is 100Hz this
>   happens after about 500 days (because
>   vxTicks wraps). At faster clock rates
>   it will happen sooner. Anyone trying
>   for several years uptime?
>
> Oh there is an undocumented upper
>   limit on the clock rate. At rates
>   above 4294 select() will fail to
>   convert its 'usec' time into the
>   correct number of ticks. (From: David
>   Laight, dsl@tadpole.co.uk)

Assuming this bug is old, I would hope that it would either return an error or do the same thing as taskDelay(0), which puts your task at the end of the ready queue.

Answer (score 0):

The task delay tick will be VIRTUALLY 10,9,..,1,0 for taskDelay(10).

The task delay tick will be VIRTUALLY -10,-11,...,-2147483648,2147483647,...,1,0 for taskDelay(-10).